# I can't import Svelte components from any other location except the parent except from the same path as the +page.svelte

Tags: import, svelte, importerror, sveltekit, lib

So, when i try to import some .js or .txt using the `$lib` or `src/lib` it works just fine, but when trying to import components that are in the `.svelte` alias it returns this error on the server and a `[500] Internal Error` on the page

```
4:52:38 PM [vite] page reload src/routes/Inner.svelte
Error: <UserDiv> is not a valid SSR component. You may need to review your build config to ensure that dependencies are compiled, rather than imported as pre-compiled modules. Otherwise you may need to fix a <UserDiv>.
    at Module.validate_component (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:142:9)
    at eval (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/src/routes/+page.svelte:14:35)
    at Module.each (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:128:10)
    at eval (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/src/routes/+page.svelte:13:39)
    at Object.$$render (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:174:16)
    at Object.default (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:74:138)
    at eval (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/layout.svelte:8:41)
    at Object.$$render (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:174:16)
    at eval (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/.svelte-kit/generated/root.svelte:63:129)
    at $$render (E:/body/vsc/svelte-learn/node_modules/svelte/src/runtime/internal/ssr.js:174:16)
```

but when i use a component in the same directory as the +page.svelte it works, what is the reason behind that?! is it fixable ?!

here is the code for the import `+page.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import {data} from "$lib/testdata.js" //works fine
    import {UserDiv} from "$lib/components/UserDiv.svelte" //doesn't work
</script>

<div>
    {#each data.users as user}
        <UserDiv {user} />
    {/each}
</div>
```

here is the component `src/lib/components/UserDiv.svelte`

```
<script>
    export let user;
</script>

<div>
    <span>id [{user.id}] belongs to {user.name} who's age {user.age}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Right.
You should import component like this:

```
import UserDiv from "$lib/components/UserDiv.svelte";
```

Please try it and let me know if it does work.
Thanks

Comment: removing the { } from the component name fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear that. If you need my help, please don't hesitate to reach out to me.
I am here to help you in any way I can.

Answer (score 0):

`import { UserDiv } from ...` is wrong, as it is a named import. Components are exported from Svelte files as the *default* export.

So if there are not other issues (- error does not sound like an import issue, though -) that should be:

```js
import UserDiv from "$lib/components/UserDiv.svelte";
```